# Oracle Business Intelligence Cloud Solutions (BICS)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

BICS dashboard prompt - Filtering fiscal year prompt to only show years greater than 2000

I am creating a dashboard that has a prompt for fiscal years. When you select the drop-down it gives the following values: (1, 2, 3, 2000, 2001, 2002, etc.) I want to create a SQL statement to only show years greater than 2000. Here is the SQL statement I have drafted.

```
SELECT "Time"."Fiscal Year" 
FROM "Financials - GL Balance Sheet" 
WHERE "Time"."Fiscal Year" >= 2000
```

Comment: I think our BICS expert answered your question on the OTN forums, so check there.

Comment: If it helps the fixed code for this issue is: SELECT "Time"."Fiscal Year" FROM "Financials - GL Balance Sheet" WHERE "Time"."Fiscal Year" >= '2000' AND "Time"."Fiscal Year" <> '4' AND "Time"."Fiscal Year" <> '5' AND "Time"."Fiscal Year" <> '3';

Comment: the real fix is to store dates as dates and not strings, but that's a different story